# Slice Functionality in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, slice

I read my .zshrc file in Swift and would like to print out all the aliases inside it.

```
func readFile(path: String) -> Int {
    errno = 0
    if freopen(path, "r", stdin) == nil {
        perror(path)
        return 1
    }
    while let line = readLine() {
        if(line.starts(with: "# alias")){
            print(line);
        }
        // do something with lines
    }
    return 0
}
```

Now the output is this

```
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
# alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3.7"
# alias python2="/usr/bin/python2"
```

I would like to slice away the `# alias` how can I do this?
I'm new to swift.

Thank's in Advance

Comment: check if your string `hasPrefix("# alias ")` and `dropFirst(8)` characters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why I have to check hasPrefix?
Before I check in the codition if it starts with "# alias"

Comment: Actually it is the same `String` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`

Comment: Drop first worked fine. Thank you @LeoDabus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to Leo Dabus

- `dropFirst(8)` works!
- or look at `RangeReplaceableCollection`